# Why is the domain of the error function scaled by $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, error-function

The normal distribution function $\Phi(z)$ has the definition
$\Phi(z) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^z e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \, dx$.

However the error function is conventionally defined such that $\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erf}(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})\equiv\Phi(z)$.

I understand the $\frac{1}{2}$ scaling on the error function itself, since the $\Phi$ integral is symmetrical around $0$. But why scale $z$ in $\operatorname{erf}(z)$??

Comment: I suspect that it's because those who adopted that convention were not probabilists. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The error function is defined by
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-t^2}\ dt\tag1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Phi (z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-x^2/2}\ dx\tag2
\end{equation}
Now, setting $x=t\sqrt{2}$ to the equation $(2)$ then the domain $0<x<z$ changes to $0<t<\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}$
\begin{align}
\Phi (z)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{{z}/{\sqrt{2}}} e^{-t^2}\cdot\sqrt{2}\ dt\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{{z}/{\sqrt{2}}} e^{-t^2}\ dt\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\!\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\!\right)
\end{align}

Comment: I get the conversion. The question is why $erf$ is defined that way. Does this definition provide an elegant solution to some known problem?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod My bad, I didn't read the question perfectly. I don't really know why but maybe this definition is more to the definer's taste. Anyway, your title is misleading so my answer isn't entirely wrong.